# Where does Disgaea 4 place Chronologically

Tags: disgaea, disgaea-4

I haven't played Disgaea 2 or 3 yet and the first Disgaea game I played was Disgaea 4. I recently got Disgaea 1 and found out Flone was just an angel and knowing the list of DLC for Disgaea 4 she apparently becomes a "Fallen Angel" sometimes during Disgaea 2 and/or 3, then is Disgaea 4 she's an Arch Angel.

So I'm just wondering where chronologically Disgaea 4 takes place, does it take place after Disgaea 3 or is it a Prequel to Digaea 2 and/or 3?

Comment: afaik all the disgaeas are only loosely connected to each other so there's really no true chronological order other than to assume 1-2-3-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no apparent chronology outside of Disgaea 1, Disgaea D2 (Disgaea's direct sequel) Disgaea 2 (an apparent, sort of sequel). As you'll learn there are many, many alternate Netherworlds (and quite possibly different timelines). When Laharl, Etna and the gang visit future games they're generally doing so from an "alternate" netherworld to whichever world your protagonist happens to inhabit.

But for what it's worth [Disgaea endgame spoilers]

> In the first Disgaea in the "Good" ending Flonne becomes a Fallen Angel, hence her existence as a Fallen Angel in most other games. I don't believe a reason is ever given for Flonne's sudden appearance as Archangel either.

Due to the above spoiler and various quotes from the Disgaea 1 characters (such as Laharl complaining about not being the main character in Disgaea 3) it does seem that Disgaea 1 happened before all other games and/or Laharl, Etna and Flonne show up in the other Netherworlds after the events of the first Disgaea.

Due to the reappearances of main characters as bonus/DLC characters in each successive generation it can be roughly assumed each game happens after the previously released games, however the remakes confuse this issue even more; certain Disgaea 3 characters now exist in Disaea 2 Dark Hero Days. But the Chronology is largely irrelevant outside of Disgaea 1/2/D2 if you consider postgame content to be non-cannon (since postgame + bonus characters is at best a time paradox/alternate universe funtime in most games), since Disgaea 3 and 4's stories exist completely separate of the D1/2 worlds.

I've only played the games and read the Disgaea 1/2 mangas though; I'm not sure what extended universe material is considered cannon or what material might give clues to the chronology.

Answer (score 0):

After having played Disgaea 3 - Absence of Detention i think the games give a logical insight as to where Disgaea 4 is placed.

1. #### Disgaea 1 - Hour/Afternoon of Darkness
2. #### Disgaea 2 - Cursed Memories/Dark Hero Days

   - Laharl is an Overload *1
   - Flonne is a Fallen Angel *1
3. #### Disgaea 3 - Absence of Justice/Detention

   - Aurum came to Evil Academy looking for the "Strongest Overload", after beating Mao's father he goes to raise Mao to be the strongest. *2
4. #### Disgaea 3 - Absence of Justice/Detention (Raspberyl Mode)

   - Mao is the Dean and Overload *3
   - Geffory is back as Geffory X because Mao "fix him" *3
   - When Beryl is in Celetria the Angels talk about demons being persistent comparing them to **Overload Laharl's** persistence* *1
   - there is a Alraune named Vulcanus*1
   - Beryl meets with the new Archangel which is Flonne who is clearly a Fallen Angel after quickly running back and changing clothes *1
5. #### Disgaea 4 - A Promise Unforgotten/Revisited

   - Flonne is an Archangel
   - Asagi is the major source of Malice for Fear the Great *4

NOTES:

*1

> Laharl's position as Overlord is unquestioned after his challenge, Vulcanus is turned into a flower by Seraph Lamington after Vulcanus's plotting is revealed, Lamington turns Floone into a Fallen Angel

*2

> [Zenon](http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Zenon) is the Strongest Overlord known as the God of All Overlords yet Aurum raises Mao as the strongest meaning True Zenon has been pacified by Adel (though showing his loves Rozalin despite the fact she's the True Zenon)

*3

> Mao's father was defeated by Aurum and was able to properly pass way after Aurum's defeat. Mao captures Aurum and experiments on him turning him into Geffory X

*4

> Asagi in Disgaea 2 is more placid and not so obsessed with being the main character to the point where she tried to steal it.

### Contradictions

Asagi and Raspberyl Mode i don't see as DLC due to them not being DLC it in the remakes of Disgaea 2 and 3 while other character appearances are (like Saphire and Almaz in Disgaea 2)

however in the remake of Disgaea 3 Fuka and Desco appear in it, given that the 2 first meet one another in Disgaea 4 that can only mean Disgaea 4 comes before Disgaea 3, yet Flonne's quick rush back when Beryl meets her could suggest Flonne hasn't gotten her Archangel gown yet (which is longer than her usual gowns)

the key point is Asagi since her goal to steal the Main character spotlight feeds Fear the Great in Disgaea 4, all i know at this point is in Disgaea 3 is that she's looking for a game where she is the main character which was stolen, i have not seen the scenes regarding these points so i am unsure if Val has helped Asagi get into a game or if Asagi's stolen game is what leads her to creating so much Malice for Fear the Great

---

I won't accept this answer until i can clear up the contradiction and find out where Disgaea D2 - A Brighter Darkness and Disgaea Infinite are placed